# How can i pass information between pages of html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cart

I'm trying to make a shopping cart that works over multiple pages, so that which ever page you add something to the cart in (StoreA.html StoreB.html), the cart on a different page (Cart.html) updates with items from all the pages of the store. I have it so that it works on only a single page where I create a div within the cart whenever a user clicks add to cart and it grabs the price and picture. I can't figure this out, I've tried using jQuery `$.get` and `$.post` methods and nothing works

this is the code for my single page adding to the cart

```js
function addToCartClicked(event) {
    var button = event.target
    var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement
    var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-title')[0].innerText
    var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-price')[0].innerText
    var imageSrc = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-image')[0].src
    if(price == '') {
      return;
    }
    addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc)
    updateCartTotal()
}

function addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc) {
    var cartRow = document.createElement('div')
    cartRow.classList.add('cart-row')
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-title')
    for (var i = 0; i < cartItemNames.length; i++) {
        if (cartItemNames[i].innerText == title) {
            alert('This item is already added to the cart')
            return
        }
    }
    var cartRowContents = `
        <div class="cart-item cart-column">
            <img class="cart-item-image" src="${imageSrc}" width="100" height="100">
            <span class="cart-item-title">${title}</span>
        </div>
        <span class="cart-price cart-column">${price}</span>
        <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
            <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">REMOVE</button>
        </div>`
    cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents
    cartItems.append(cartRow)
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')[0].addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0].addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
}
```

Comment: Conside looking into setting cookies or using localStorage/sessionStorage

Comment: localStorage, Cookie or if the cart item data is small pass the params in the URL but that can get messy.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to use some sort of localStorage or sessionStorage.

You would want to do something like

`localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items);`

though you would probably need to store an array using JSON.stringify().

You would then retrieve the information using

`const items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItems('items'));`

You could also look into indexedDB which is a client side DB, but browser support isn't great yet.

Comment: You might also want to listen for changes and update the cart using
`window.addEventListener('storage', () => { });`